# Young engineer not wanting to work in academia: is PhD worth it?

Tags: phd, career-path, job, engineering, france

I'll soon get my engineering diploma (~MSc, from a "renowned-but-not-in-the-top-3" so-called french *grande école*).
The degree itself is not specialized, but I mainly studied mechanical and industrial engineering.
I aim to work in the industry – or, in other words, I don't want to make an academic career.

So I'm now wondering if doing a PhD in France (i.e. during 3 years) would be worth it, regarding my estimated career plan.
**Question:** What would then be **pros and cons I should consider** before choosing to do (or not) a PhD?

---

<sub>Here are some questions I've already consulted, but did not fully answered my questions:</sub>

- <sub>[Is PhD worth it when considering your career in industry](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11993/50010)</sub>
- <sub>[What skills can I get during a PhD to be competitive on the job market against non-PhD holders?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27596/50010)</sub>

Comment: What country do you want to work as an engineer in?  France only, or others?  Also, there is actually an engineering SE; I don't know that community, but it might be worth looking there for your question as well.

Comment: Although you state in your question that you consulted other questions on this site, and that those questions did not fully answer your question, it is unclear _why_ those questions do not fully answer your current question. I suggest editing your question to emphasize how exactly your situation is not addressed in other questions on this topic.

Comment: I don't know whether the same is true in France, but in the USA, although the PhD is the most well-known terminal degree for engineers, it is not the only one.  There's also a "Doctor of Engineering" degree that may be more helpful for someone intending a career outside academia.

Comment: Don't do a PhD if you don't find the studying and the research inherently rewarding.